# GDB Python Scripting Error on Windows: "Undefined command: 'import'"

Tags: python, linux, windows, gdb

I am using GDB for debugging on Windows 10, and I have a Python script that I want to execute within GDB. The script is responsible for writing data to a specific memory address while debugging. However, when I attempt to run the script with GDB using the source command, I encounter an error on the first line, which contains the "import gdb" statement.

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
write_memory.py:1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "import". Try "help".
```

The strange thing is that on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04), the same Python script works flawlessly with GDB using the source command:

`(gdb) source write_memory.py`

I am using GDB version "GNU gdb (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.Rel1 (Build arm-12.24)) 12.1.90.20221210-git" on Windows 10. It appears that GDB on Windows does not support Python scripting with the source command.

My question is: Is there any way to run Python scripts within GDB on Windows, or is there an alternative approach to achieve the memory write operation in this context?

Any help or insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show your `memory write operation`, then we might be able to suggest a workaround without python. Or you try to find a gdb with python support built in.

Comment: I run this command;
(gdb) python print("Hello, world!") and I got this message
"Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB. "

I don't think the error has anything to do with the script and you can assume that the script consists only of the "import gdb" line.

Comment: That's why I wrote you could try to find a gdb with python support built in.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that GDB on Windows does not support Python scripting with the source command.

*This version* of GDB was compiled without Python support.

You should build your own copy *with* Python support, or ask your toolchain provider to do so.